# NEST 7 ignore a property mapping but still available in _source

Tags: nest

How can this mapping be converted using NEST 7 client. I'm trying to set the enabled setting to false. Which will causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely but still make it available from the _source.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      },
      "last_updated": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "session_data": { 
        "type": "object",
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html)

```
await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents", c => c
    .Map<Document>(m => m.AutoMap()));

public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Object(Enabled = false)]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

another one is to use [fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html)

```
await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents", c => c
    .Map<Document>(m => m
        .Properties(p => p.Object<object>(o => o.Name(n => n.Data).Enabled(false)))));
```

You can find more in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html).

Hope that helps.